# Proofs involving a $d$-regular bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> Suppose that $G$ is a $d$-regular bipartite graph with bipartition $(A, B)$, and that $d ≥ 1$.
>
> a) Prove that $∣A∣ = ∣B∣$.
>
> b) Prove that $G$ contains a perfect matching.

So I understand that a $d$-regular graph will have every vertex of degree $d$. But I am not sure how that would apply here. Will I have to insert $d$ into my use of Hall's condition and then move from there. And also, how exactly would I prove that $|A| = |B|$? Would that also involve Hall's condition?

Thank you!

Comment: For a), count the number of edges "leaving" $A$ and the number of edges "leaving" $B$. These numbers have to be equal, since they are exactly all the edges of the graph (you can't have edges between vertices in A or edges between vertices in B because the graph is bipartite). Since the graph is d-regular, the edges leaving A are exactly $d|A|$. For the same reason, the edges leaving B are exactly $d|B|$. Therefore $|A|=|B|$.